# why does variable assignment not work on lists sometimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mutability

Python beginner here. Confused about the nature of list assignment.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = a.reverse()
```

```
>>>a 
>>>[3,2,1]
>>>b
>>> # nothing shows up
```

or

```
e = [1,2,3]
f = e.append(4)
```

```
>>>e 
>>>[1,2,3,4]
>>>f
>>> # nothing shows up
```

Why does assigning to b or f not work here.
I believe it has to do with the mutability of lists? Am i completely wrong? Thanks

Comment: because those methods return `None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both these methods do an `in-place` modification, i.e.:

```
b = a.reverse()
f = e.append(4)
```

They modify the original object and do not create a new one. Hence, you see `None` when you try and print these.

As per @juanpa.arrivillaga:

**Note:** The fact that these methods return None is a convention.

Comment: To go into a bit more detail, `.reverse()` returns `None`, so what is happening here is that you are trying to assign b to the result of a.reverse(), which yields `None`. Alternatively, you can assign `b` to `a` after you make the reversal, or use splice.

Comment: Note, the fact that these methods return `None` is a *convention*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Edited my answer to have the `note`.

Comment: Thank you so much Mayank Porwal! Your explanation clarified this for me.